# Database changes, backward compatibility , Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, backwards-compatibility

My context: C#, EF, SQL Server 2012.

There are 2 separate applications (services), let's call them X and Y.

- Service X = web service API that is used for our external clients to communicate with our product.
- Service Y = our Youtube service that communicates using google API.

X & Y run separately, there is no communication, but they have access to the same database.

Example: External client provides data using `X` api. It is stored in database.
`Y` service looks at database and processes ( uploads / synchronizes videos in youtube channel.)

Now business dictates : additional data needs to be added.

So API of X needs to be extended. And Database needs to be extended.

Y needs to be updated to process new data.

Dilemma is: we have many clients. They all have their own database. We do not want to update all their databases.

We do not have multiple versions of service Y. So they will all get the new version of service Y.

So service Y will have to work with both OLD and NEW version of database.

Service X will only be updated , when the database is updated... so there is no problem.

Service Y uses Entity Framework, (code is not generated).

How can I make sure service Y will work in both cases ?:

- OLD: columns do NOT exist in database.
- NEW: columns exist in database.

Anybody have any Ideas ????

Comment: I read this related topic : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/294fdabc-fb8c-44a2-b3fd-4df30a868af4/optional-columns-in-entity-framework?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Answer (score 0):

Case NEW: This shouldn't be a problem with

> new version of service Y

and new database.

Case OLD: This is what causes the backward-compatibility issue as EF crashes due to mapping error. One option is to rebuild a model based on old database structure and to keep it in a class library ready to be dropped in for Y. Another is the code-first approach.

Furthur reading:

[Backwards compatibility when data store changes](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a36bbd83-37da-46dd-bf42-edaa51a2ff34/backwards-compatibility-when-data-store-changes?forum=adodotnetentityframework)

[on code-first](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907.aspx#codefirst)